# Windows 10 disk usage 100% and lagging too much but Ubuntu works smoothely

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, lag

I am having two operating systems in my laptop, **Ubuntu** and **Windows 10** (Recently Installed Latest Version).

**Ubuntu** works **best** in performance and performs heavy functions *lag-lessly*.

**Windows 10** worked smoothely around 10 minutes after installing and suddenly started lagging very much. On clicking start menu, it pops up after 2-5 Minutes.

On task manager , the ram usage was 10-20% only but disk usage was uniformely 100% with no programs that were using disk.

I tried many solutions available on net like : **disabling** `superfetch` and `Windows Search`, but none worked for me :(

## Facts:

> **Ram** : 2GB
>
> *I installed only Chrome Browser after installing Windows 10*
>
> **EDIT** : Uninstalled Chrome, still same

Please help me.

Comment: How full is the partition that Windows 10 is on?  If it's more than 90% full, you're going to have virtual memory issues.  Also, 2 GB or RAM is really on the low end for Windows 10.

Comment: Partition of Windows 10 is empty and of size about 200GB

Comment: Have you scanned for viruses?

Comment: Yes, even did full PC scan with `Advanced SystemCare` that includes : Disk Optimization, Disk Check, System Check, and many more. No errors were found.

Comment: 2GB for using Chrome under Win10 is not enough. no wonder that windows is slow, it must page out data to pagefile

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have already uninstalled chrome. :( then also the problem persists

Comment: Please provide *the exact make and model* of your CPU and motherboard.

Comment: 2GB is still not enough. Windows still pages data to pagefile. use ubuntu most time

Comment: Run **Resource and Performance Monitor** (`perfmon.exe`) and see what programs and services are using the disk.

Answer (score -2):

mmm i thought you if stop windows search and Superfetch services doesn't work 
you should reinstall your windows or upgrade your hardware
Read this Solution
[fix 100% disk usage in Windows 10](https://www.thetruebox.com/ask/16/help-me-to-fix-100%25-disk-usage-in-windows-10)

Comment: Have formatted whole hard disk, tried reinstalling 2+ times.

Comment: You should quote and cite the content from your reference link.  Link-only answers are not that helpful, as links like yours, can stop working.  Your answer by itself answer the propose question.

Comment: The link is now dead. The website doesn't exist any more.